# T-SQL Compare a group of rows with other groups of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, rows

So I'm trying to filter one table by the values of multiple rows grouped by one column which match multiple rows of another table which are grouped by a column.  For Exmaple:

```
###Table1###
+--------+-------+
| Symbol | Value |
+--------+-------+
| A      |     1 |
| A      |     2 |
| A      |     3 |
| B      |     9 |
| B      |     8 |
+--------+-------+

###Table2###
+--------+-------+
| Symbol | Value |
+--------+-------+
| C      |     9 |
| C      |     8 |
| D      |     1 |
| D      |     2 |
| D      |     4 |
| E      |     9 |
| E      |     8 |
| F      |     1 |
| F      |     2 |
| F      |     3 |
+--------+-------+
```

The query needs to return C, E, and F but not D because the values for A match the values of F, and the values of B match the values of C and E.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, the formatting for the tables didn't work.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the concept of _relational division_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the match by joining the tables on the value and then counting the symbols.  For your data, this should work:

```
select t2.symbol, t1.symbol
from (select t1.*, count(*) over (partition by symbol) as cnt
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.value = t2.value
group by t1.symbol, t2.symbol, t1.cnt;
having count(*) = t1.cnt
```

This assumes:

- No duplicates in either table.
- You are looking for rows in `table2` that match `table1`, but `table2` could have additional values not in `table1`.

Comment: I truly appreciate the effort but I'm afraid this doesn't quite answer the problem.  You see, all the values for the symbol from table 1 have to be in the values for the table 2 symbol to be a match.  Your solution seems to just be matching up every potential match of value to value.

Comment: @SteveBishop . . . I'm not quite sure what your comment is supposed to mean.  This should be returning symbols in the second table that match symbols in the first table by having the same values.  I just edited the answer because I misplaced the `having` clause.  Perhaps that caused confusion.

Comment: Yeah I didn't have the having statement in there.  That could have been the problem.  I'll run it again and see if that fixes it.  Thank you again.

Comment: So your solution works for the question I asked and I've marked it as the answer.  Unfortunately it appears I did not really give enough details about my actual problem for your solution to answer my current issue.  Still, your solution is brilliant and you deserve the credit for it.

Comment: @SteveBishop . . . I encourage you to ask another question with the appropriate details.  Also, set up a SQL Fiddle with sample data.